# On cascade delete with disjoint specialization on MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have the following DB model:

"Entity" (base DB entity) with disjoint types:

- "Person"
- "Group"
- "Project"
- ...plus some more...

(I hope I use the terminology correctly, but I mean to say that an entity should always be either a person, a group or a project.) These are implemented by the corresponding tables:

- entity (id, ...)
- person (fk entity_id on update cascase on delete cascade, ...)
- group (fk entity_id on update cascase on delete cascade, ...)
- project (fk entity_id on update cascase on delete cascade, ...)

When I delete an entity row, the deletion gets cascaded onto the (say) person row. However, when I delete a person row, it doesn't get cascaded onto the entity row. There is a lot of data tied to the entity table, and I would therefore like to make sure that the DB is kept consistent at all times (ie. entity row deleted when disjoint type row is deleted).

The only recommendation I have seen is to include a back-referencing FK in the base (entity) table, which would be cumbersome (there are now 6 entity types and more may be coming).

What would be a clean way of doing this? Triggers?

Comment: <opinion>The clean way to do such is in your application code.  `FOREIGN KEYs` are sometimes more trouble than they are worth.</opinion>.  You do have application code?  You are not simply manually typing commands, correct?

Comment: correct, of course. But sometimes I have to delete data manually. And anyway, I feel that data integrity should to be enforced on DB level whenever possible (no-one is insured against bugs in code).

Comment: @RickJames that would be pretty funny. Random DML cmds as a front end

Comment: A database layer, possibly with Stored Procedures, can hide the miscellany you need to maintain the links, etc.